# Docker cannot detect the project

Tags: python, django, docker

I am new to coding and my employer told me to learn docker. I tried this [guide](https://realpython.com/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/.)

But when I get to step

```
docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python manage.py)migrate
```

it gives me the next error:

> cannot import name 'views' from 'docker_django'

What can I do to avoid it?
I tried moving views.py from there to here but it didn't help

Here are settings.py

```
    import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', 'NO').lower() in ('on', 'true', 'y', 'yes')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # apps
    'docker_django.apps.todo',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'docker_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'docker_django.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_SERVICE'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT']
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )
# print(STATICFILES_DIRS)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here's docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
```

Here's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY...
```

Comment: Please add your settings, the `Dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yaml` file.